# How to Handle Selecting options?

Tags: tabs, options, many-options, alternatives

is their any alternative to tab? I'am currently handling a design that requires too many options per tab in a page. so lets say for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing what exactly the options are and who you're designing for.

There are definitely alternatives, though: e.g. pages instead of tabs, like in the Android, iOS, macOS, and Windows system settings.

You might also be able to save space by:

- using progressive disclosure (showing some options only once they're relevant)
- hiding niche options in a dialog ("Advanced settings...", "Customize...", "Tweak privacy settings...", etc.)
- clustering options that only make sense together (e.g. "Night mode" instead of "Dim screen at night" + "Dim navigation bar at night")
- getting rid of options that don't make sense
- using extensions instead of options in some cases, etc.